# if(s1.Contains(s2)) Seems to always be true

Tags: java, string, contains

sorry, changed the question slightly.

essentially i want to know if `aString` contains `String`. My issue is when comparing say `aS` *a substring of `aString`)* `"aS".contains("String")` shows true.

`String a="st", b="string";`
I ran `System.out.println(a.contains(b));`
That returned `false`, as expected. I have an understanding of contains, i must be missing something else.

So It had seemed that my program was working properly, but I made some adjustments and came back and the whole thing stopped working. I sussed out what are usually the common culprits `(brackets, file io, etc.)`. I found `if(string.contains(string))` would continually run, ie: always true. not sure why this is happening, probably something I missed in the code.

This is an example of my output (Just a char by char reading of the file):

`I
n
t
e
g
e
r
G
;`

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class comp{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> lines = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> symbolTable = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<String> parsedFile = new ArrayList<String>();


         try {
                File file = new File("symbolTable.txt");
                Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()&&symbolTable.add(scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase()));
                scanner.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


         try {
                File file = new File("APU_CS400_input.txt");
                Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
                while (scanner.hasNextLine()&&lines.add(scanner.nextLine().replaceAll("\\s+","").toLowerCase()));
                scanner.close();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }


         //runs through line by line of the input file
         for(String line: lines){
             String sBuild = "";
             StringBuilder identifier = new StringBuilder("");

             //moves through the line char by char
             for(int i=0;line.length()>i; i++){
                 sBuild+=line.charAt(i);
                 //moves through the symbol table comparing each symbol to each string 
                 //that is built char by char
                 for(String symbol: symbolTable){
                     //if the char string matches the symbol then any identifiers are saved and 
                     //symbols are saved, the string is then reset to empty
            //This is where i seem to get an issue

        ***if(sBuild.contains(symbol)){***
                        if(symbol.length()<sBuild.length()){
                            identifier.append(sBuild,0,sBuild.length()-symbol.length()); 
                            parsedFile.add(identifier.toString());
                            identifier.delete(0,sBuild.length()-symbol.length());
                        }
                        sBuild="";
                        parsedFile.add(symbol);
                     }

                 }
             }
         }


         for(String symbol:parsedFile){
             System.out.println(symbol);
         }

    }

}

Blockquote
```

Comment: Why would it not be true?

Comment: Indeed, it always **should** be true.

Comment: "Sorry, changed the question slightly"--that's a typo, it should read "sorry, changed the question radically to something completely different".

Comment: If `sBuild.contains(symbol)` returns true when you believe it should be false, maybe `sBuild` and/or `symbol` are not the values you think they are. This is where **debugging** is used to figure out what is going wrong. *You should try it!*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> essentially i want to know if "aString" contains "String".

Yes, `"aString"` as a string-value does contain the string-value of `"String"`

> *My issue is when comparing say "aS" (a substring of "aString") "aS".contains("String") shows true.*

Are you sure? This **cannot be**, therefore I rather suspect bugs in your code.

---

To spare youself of "empty String symbols" consider this:

```
try {
  File file = new File("symbolTable.txt");
  Scanner scanner=new Scanner(file);
  while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
    // toLowerCase will do nothing for characters that are not letters
    // Don't spend CPU cycles with regex
    String symbolLine=scanner.nextLine().toLowerCase();
    // Collect the symbol only if non-empty?? This will save you from empty symbols
    if(symbolLine.trim().length()>0) {
      symbolTable.add(symbolLine); // or .add(symbolLine.trim()) ???
    }
  }
  scanner.close();
} catch (Exception ex) {
  ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Took your advice and led me to the answer, I was not taking into account newline at the end of my files. Man was that frustrating, and explains why it was working before I edited my symbol table. THANKS!

Comment: you had mentioned that regex was a slow way to remove white-spaces so i went with trim. What would you recommend for removing "/n"? because i am currently using a regex .replace("\n", "").

Comment: @user3674515 trim will take care about `\n` too - read [trim javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim--) - removes anything that is lesser or equal to `0x20` (space) from the beginning and end of the string. `\n` is `0x0A`.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it this way.

```
s1.contains(s2)
```

should return `true`, if a substring of `s1` can be found such that

```
s1.substring(i, j).equals(s2)
```

is true.

If `s2` is an empty string, then `i = 0, j = 0` is one such substring, so `contains()` returns `true`.

As it should.

Comment: would "st".contain("string") be true?

Comment: @user3674515 Of course not. Can you find a substring of `"st"` that is equal to `"string"`? No.

Answer (score 1):

`if(String.Contains(""))` always **should** be true, as long as the String is not null.

Comment: right, slightly out of context though, i rephrased my question to make more sense.

Comment: @user3674515: out of context? Your question title was totally borked.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to look at this one a bit mathematically to see why `s.contains("")` is always true.  Suppose you think of this this way:

> `a.contains(b)` is true if there are some values `i` and `j` such that `a.substring(i,j)` is equal to `b`.

If you think about it a bit, you'll see that this is exactly what `contains` means when the argument is a nonempty string like `"xyz"`.  If there is some `substring` of `x` that equals `"xyz"`, then `s.contains("xyz")` is true.  If there is no such substring, then `s.contains("xyz")` is false.

So it makes sense that the same logic would apply for an empty string, since it applies everywhere else.  And it's always true that `a.substring(0,0)` equals `""` (if `a` is not null).  That's why `a.contains("")` should always be true.

It may not be intuitively obvious from the English meaning of "contains", but when you're dealing with "edge cases" like this, you sometimes have to think in different terms.  Often, the Javadoc spells things out so that you can easily figure out what happens in the edge cases, without relying on intuition.  Unfortunately, in this case, they didn't.

Comment: And no, I didn't see Andreas' answer before I posted this, even though we just happened to use the same index variable names.  I think "great minds think alike" applies here... :) :)

Comment: right, an empty string would always match. My question (revised) is why when I have a string a="I" and string b="integer", and i say a.contains(b) does it result in true.

Comment: You should not revise your question like that.  It's OK to revise questions to provide more info or correct errors or improve the wording or formatting. But when you change it into a totally different question after people have posted answers, you make the answerers look like idiots.  That's not a good way to treat the people who volunteer their time trying to help.  If you have a different question, post a different question.

Comment: I apologize, and will keep that in mind for next time. Did not expect so many answers to the title alone out of context of what I wrote.

Comment: @user3674515 You in programming now. You should get used to the fact that what you write matters. Because it does when writing code. If you write part of the code wrong, you will not get the result you seek. Exactly like what happened with this question. You didn't write the question correctly, so you didn't get answer that could help you. **In programming, what you write matters.** Does too in real life, but people are more forgiving about it than computers. Learn to be precise.